# Sorting Hashed maps Map<String,?>

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am trying to sort and get the top 3 maxium values for the VALUE(?)

```
Map<String,?> points = map
```

Tried using `Map<String, String>` and it works fine, but in this case I need `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: i hope u are storing string as key and map as value in sorted map i.e treeMap probably. So whats the issue. First 3 values are the ones you are looking for

Comment: the map that it gets is unsorted, its actually and XML file with random NAME, ? Values

Comment: you should use treemap instead of hashmap

Comment: `TreeMap` keeps the *keys* sorted, not the values.

Comment: It is unlikely you're going to be able to sort values of an *unknown type*. Whatever it is you're trying to do, that's not how you do it.

Comment: This does not seem to be a reasonable thing to do, even if it were possible. If you explain why you need to do this it may help us to see if it's the right approach

Answer (score 0):

The type of the values will need to implement `Comparable`.

If the size of the map is not too large, you could try something like this:

```
private <T extends Comparable> SortedSet<T> sortValues(final Map<?, T> m)
    {
    final SortedSet<T> result = new TreeSet<>();
    result.addAll(m.values());
    return result;
    }
```

I haven't tested this, but I think I have all of the type declarations correct.  Then just take the first, or last as the case may be, elements from the sorted set.  I believe you can optionally provide your own `Comparator` to the set to choose how to order the objects.

Comment: i am getting this error :
Bound mismatch: The generic method sortValues(Map<?,T>) of type ScorePage is not applicable for the arguments (Map<capture#3-of ?,capture#4-of ?>). The inferred type capture#4-of ? is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable> ScorePage.java

Comment: The error is telling you that the declared type ('capture#4-of ?') of your value does not implement `Comparable`.  It is not possible to sort objects that are not comparable, unless you create a `Comparator` which defines how you want to compare the objects.  Note that each '?' defines a separate type, thus the "capture #x" in the message.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort non-`Comparable` objects, to begin with, so you'll need a map with `Comparable` values, not `?`. Having that, however, you could do something like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sortValues(Map<?, T> map) {
    List<T> buffer = new ArrayList<T>(map.values());
    Collections.sort(buffer);
    return(buffer);
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the return value of `sortValues`, such as picking the first three objects in it.